# Does residual autocorrelation beyond the first lag have any implication in a regular regression?

Tags: correlation, standard-error, residuals, regression-coefficients

I have seen the review of a multiple regression analysis using time series with a quarterly frequency.  The original modeler advanced that the model's residuals were not autocorrelated by disclosing a Durbin Watson score that was reasonably close to 2.0.  But, the model reviewer using an autocorrelation analysis more often seen in ARIMA, tested both the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation going back up to 15 quarter lags.  Next, he calculated the Confidence Interval associated with such autocorrelation.  Given that the sample was reasonably large with about 250 quarterly-data observations,  the resulting CI of those correlations was pretty narrow.  As a result, the model reviewer indicated that the regression model suffered from residual autocorrelation because some of the lags beyond t-1 were associated with residual autocorrelation that were deemed statistically significant (beyond the 95% CI, where an autocorrelation could be deemed not different than zero).

I thought the above residual analysis was unconventional and more appropriate for an ARIMA modeling effort.  I also wondered about the relevance of any residual autocorrelation beyond the 1st quarter lag.  The latter is the only one associated with truly chained or linked datapoints.  At the 1 quarter lag, if the residuals are reasonably highly correlated, they could definitely trend by having the same sign for numerous consecutive periods.  This is much less the case or often not at all with any greater quarter lag.  The residuals will not trend as indicated.  I figured this is probably why the DB score focused on the first period lag appears to be the dominant metric of residual autocorrelation.

Also, let's say you do have residual autocorrelation even upon the very first lag.  Is'nt there a rule or something that states if you have a large enough sample (maybe > 100 observations).  The residual autocorrelation will not matter anyway because due to the large sample the statistical significance of the regression coefficients will be pretty much unaffected.  This may be an offshoot of the Central Limit Theorem.

What do you think?